# Groovy - outputs objects from a g:each in specific way

Tags: grails, groovy, syntax

Currently I am passing through a group of objects, shifts, to a gsp page and printing them out like so:

```
<g:each in="${shifts}">
    ${it.dayOfWeek}    -    <g:formatDate format="hh:mm a" date="${it.fromTime}" />    -    <g:formatDate format="hh:mm a" date="${it.toTime}" /> 
</g:each>
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Monday    -    12:30 AM    -    12:45 AM 

    Monday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM 

    Tuesday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM 

    Wednesday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM //etc
```

So from the example above, in shifts there are two objects where the day of the week is Monday. Disregarding order of times, how can I get objects with the same day of week to print out something like this (for the above example):

```
    Monday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM    -    12:30 AM    -    12:45 AM 

    Tuesday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM 

    Wednesday    -    12:00 AM    -    12:15 AM
```

Edit*

```
// Sumbitted Email
static deliverSubmittedToOwner(Schedule schedule) {
    def shifts = schedule.shifts.sort { shift -> days.indexOf(shift.dayOfWeek) }
    shifts = shifts.groupBy{shifts.dayOfWeek}
    println shifts
    sendMail(to: session.user.email, subject: 'Your Flex Schedule submitted!',
        view:'/email/schedule_submitted_to_owner',schedule:schedule,shifts:shifts)
}
```

Comment: Don't do whatever it is you're doing to create the newline if it's the same day as before? Although I'd probably do this kind of work outside of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` on your shifts.  This turns your list of shift days into a map of lists of days: `shifts.groupBy{it.dayOfWeek}`.  Then iterate the map and elements (the key is the day of week, the value is the list of days).

Comment: Where can I call this though? See my edit to see what im doing with shifts to pass it on to this gsp page/email im sending

Comment: this print should give you the map, right? then adopt your g:each in your view. it.key now is your dayOfWeek and it.value is the list of days. so you need another g:each within.

Comment: If i do a group by, then i cant do my sort that I need afterwards. I get a no such property: dayOfWeek for a linked has map error. Can I change that somehow tos ort based off the key?